# Using nested with_items tasks in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have 2 `with_item` tasks in ansible and I want to combine these two tasks and use  nested with items.

I want to do something like this..

```
    - debug: msg="{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ IP.split(',') }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ item.json.Password }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ password.results }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - [ "{{ IP.split(',') }}" ]
        - [ "{{ password.results.json.Password }}" ]
```

The first 2 tasks are running successfully. but 3rd task giving error as

`"fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'json'"}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```yaml
  with_nested:
    - "{{ IP.split(',') }}"
    - "{{ password.results|json_query('[].json.Password') }}"
```

---

> Q: *Error 'You need to install jmespath'*

A: It's also possible to use filter *map*. For example

```yaml
  with_nested:
    - "{{ IP.split(',') }}"
    - "{{ password.results|map(attribute='json.Password')|list }}"
```